# Webpage display on iPhone 5

Tags: html, css, iphone

My webpage [www.tolka.nu](http://www.tolka.nu) will create a gap in the text while word wrapping around a image. This only occurs using a iPhone 5 or older. Please see the attached print screen. How do I solve this?

[Print screen of webpage on iPhone 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uid4f.png)

Comment: remove float:right in .alignright in mobile

Comment: @silviagreen
Thank you...however, now the isn't wrapping at all. See here: http://imgur.com/84JpoXh

Comment: Do you still want text next to the image even in space is so reduced?

Comment: @silviagreen Yes, I want it to look like this (print screen from iPhone 6S) even on iPhone 5: http://imgur.com/WqVXQXn